# Alternate way to switch to a window handle using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, webview, selenium-webdriver

I am testing an webview app containing multiple webviews/pages. To get the webviews I do:

```
$driver.window_handles
```

which returns me an array of window indexes of numbers something like `['1', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8']`

Now if I want to switch to a specific window which contains text "My TITLE"; I have to iterate through each of the indexes in the array using loop and switch the window to that index and then check if the text is present in that window.

Eg:

```
$driver.switch_to.window('1') if 'My Title' not found; $driver.switch_to.window('3') and so on until I find the window.
```

I even tried to look for the title of the window/driver; but for some windows I am getting title as nil so wasn't a best way for me to find out the window.

Is there any other way I can try to get the required window?

Answer (score 4):

You can take the below approach:

```
#create a array with window_id and its corresponding window page title
wnd_titl = driver.window_handles.map do |w|
  driver.switch_to.window(w)
  [w,driver.title]
end

#required window
win_id = wnd_titl.find { |e1,e2| e2 == 'My TITLE' }.first
driver.switch_to.window(win_id) #switched to the required window
```